# Parsing list of strings in javascript sent from Python

Tags: parsing

I am sending a list from Python to Javascript like 
lis=['w','d'] and calling str(lis) in python.In javascript I am not able to parse this list

Comment: 1) Use [JSON to output from Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dump) 2) Use [JSON as input in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) 3) Profit.

Comment: when I am doing JSON.parse it is showing                                       JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data,I tried to get the type in Javascript ,it is showing as string

Comment: Then it's bogus "JSON". Take some time to view what the value *really* is. The issue probably relates to not following #1 or otherwise incorrectly transmitting the data.